# setting a property in a loop in ant

Tags: regex, ant, properties

If i understand correctly, once a property is bound to a value in ant, it cannot be reassigned to a value. I am using a propertyregex on a path to do some complex regex mapping, is there any way to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 3):

I found that the propertyregex has an override attribute which can be used to override the previous value in a loop. works for me.

Comment: This is link to the documentation of propertyregex http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/propertyregex.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the propertyregex stuff, but the variable task in ant is mutable (though discouraged). See http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/variable_task.html